# Unexpected token < Uncaught Syntax Error?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does my code not run without errors? I am trying to create a function that contains a couple of lines of javascript but I'm getting the error Uncaught syntaxerror. Why is that?

```
function fbpixel(){


!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

fbq('init', '202225353513153');
fbq('track', "PageView");
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=202225353513153&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
/></noscript>

};
```

Comment: Because those HTML tags aren't JavaScript.

Comment: Why are we looking at minified code?  Why is there an html `<noscript>` element inline in your Javascript?  That's probably the problem...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question will be unlikely to help anyone else. Doing some research before asking a question, and presenting a [mcve] would help.

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript code includes some code that is not javascript.

<**noscript**> is an html tag, not javascript code,  assuming, you are including the javascript code in an html page, you should include javascript code inside the <**script**> tag, and the fallback content inside the <**noscript**> tag.

For example you can fix your code like this:

```
 <!--Javascript code-->
<script type="html/javascript">
<!--
function fbpixel() {

    ! function(f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
        if (f.fbq) return;
        n = f.fbq = function() {
            n.callMethod ?
                n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
        };
        if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n;
        n.push = n;
        n.loaded = !0;
        n.version = '2.0';
        n.queue = [];
        t = b.createElement(e);
        t.async = !0;
        t.src = v;
        s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
        s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s)
    }(window,
        document, 'script', 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

    fbq('init', '202225353513153');
    fbq('track', "PageView");
}
//-->
</script>
<!--Fallback content-->
<noscript>
   <img height="1" width="1" style="display:none" src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=202225353513153&ev=PageView&noscript=1" />
</noscript>
```